# How to strip off digits at beginning using sed?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have pipe separated file. I want to strip off digits starting with '00' of sub id keeping rest of numbers same.
For eg:
Karen Calvert50335491|**0020380050335491**|ACTIVE|100|KINGSPORT|KarenCalvert50335491@charter.net|8353/3000|RESIDENTIAL|FiberNode|TENNESSEE|00:00:00:20:0f:03|EAST|423-343-9250|HSIPLUS|1826 HIGHLAND ST|Service1|MA|01602

expected o/p-

Karen Calvert50335491|**20380050335491**|ACTIVE|100|KINGSPORT|KarenCalvert50335491@charter.net|8353/3000|RESIDENTIAL|FiberNode|TENNESSEE|00:00:00:20:0f:03|EAST|423-343-9250|HSIPLUS|1826 HIGHLAND ST|Service1|MA|01602

Note:In this file there are some mac address also wich are satritng with '00'

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
 sed 's/^\([^|]*\)|0*\([^|]*\)/\1|\2/' input
```

Which matches, captures and preserves the first column in `\1` via `^\([^|]*\)` and captures the second column in `\2`, skipping the leading 0's via `0*\([^|]*\)`. Then it replaces the matched part (columns 1 and 2) with the captured parts of these columns via `/\1|\2/`.

Comment: You saved my tons of time.Great!
Thanks a lot for this help and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([^|]*\|)0+/\1/' file
```

or more generally:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^|]*\|){1})0+/\1/' file
```

where in this case `1` is the `nth -1` field

Answer (score 1):

Good grief. Try the sed solutions if you wanted to manipulate the 7th field instead of the second one. Just use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {sub(/^0+/,"",$2);print}' file
```

If you wanted to change the 7th field instead of the 2nd, you'd just change $2 to $7.

Comment: Great.It works but i think time consumption is more as compared to sed solution.

Comment: I doubt it but even if so would a marginal difference in time consumption be a bigger issue than maintainability for your input set? Besides the obvious of just having to work on a different field, what if, for example, you ever had to modify your script to at the end print a count of how many times you did the substitution (or do ANYTHING else)? In awk you'd tweak the script to add a count as `...{count+=sub()...} END{print count}`. In sed I dread to think the cryptic convolutions of letters and punctuation marks you'd have to invoke.

Comment: I guess your comment holds point when we really want to do some additional operations 'AWK' is really useful for field/string manipulation. 
Thanks